# Resume Activity

Tags: java, android

I have 3 activities let's say MainActivity, Activity 2, and Activity 3.

In the MainActivity I have a button (start/stop) when I click on this button an animation start but when I go to activity 2 or activity 3 and I comeback to MainActivity the animation stopped by itself.

But me I want that the animation of the MainActivity never stop until I click the button stop.

I tried this code in AndroidManifest.xml but it doesn't work.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: can you show us the code for the animation? It will help us to understand better what is going on. Also, If you have further relevant details please add them to your question.

Comment: post your code..

Comment: Sorry I can't post the code... What I want is to resume the main activity and not restart

Answer (score 1):

If you go back from `MainActivity` then your Activity will be Destroyed if you do not fire an `Intent` in `onbackPressed()` regardless of `launchMode`. 
`launchMode` are  instruction for how the activity should be launched. On stack pop it will destroy anyway. Read [launchModes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode) .

**Solution:-**  Solution to your problem `SharedPreference`. Save the current state of animation and restart it with previous state when `Activity` relaunched.